# Does Doctrine provide support for polymorphic relationship?

Tags: database-design, doctrine-orm, relational-database, polymorphic-associations

There is a type/table `EveryoneNeedsMe`/`everyone_needs_me` (in my concrete case it's `Message`/`messages`). And actually there are multiple types/tables, that need it, e.g. `Foo`/`foo` or `Bar`/`bar`. I'd like to use the polymorphic relationship pattern (or polymorphic associations):

```
objects_to_enm
- id
- everyone_needs_me_id
- object_type // e.g. "foo" or "bar"
- object_id // the foo's or bar's IDs
// The combination of object_type and object_id has to be UNIQUE.
```

[image: everyone-needs-me]

Some ORMs (e.g. Eloquent, s. [docu](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)) support the polymorphic relationship pattern. Does Doctrine 2 support it as well?

If yes: How to use it in Doctrine 2? If no: How to handle this case with Doctrine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Doctrine support multiple Inheritance mapping. 
But if I clearly understand you want to each entity have own table in DB.

So you can do something like this, define parent class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"foo"="Foo","bar"="Bar"})
 */
abstract class ParentClass
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Message")
     */
    protected $message;

   //getter,setter,other code
}
```

Your class `Foo` and `Bar` will extend `ParentClass` e.g.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Foo extends ParentClass
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $body;
}
```

So after that you can do

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setId(1);
$foo->setBody('Some Text');
$foo->setMessage($messageObject);
$entityManager->persist($foo);
$entityManager->flush();
```

After this in `parentclass` table you will get something like

```
| id         | message_id | discr      |
|------------|------------|------------|
| 1          |        1*  |     foo
```

and then in you code you can

```
$fooObject = $entityManager->getRepository(ParentClass::class)->find(1);
```

Doctrine will automatically return object that are persisted with that `id` in this example `Foo` object.

Full documentation, an other way how to deal with inheritance mapping, like `"SINGLE_TABLE"` you can check at [doctrine-project](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping).